# change photos metadata by given time

Tags: metadata

My camera's batteries run out and the stored date was wrong and the I have now about 100 photos with an incorrect date. Is there any app that can change the photos date? Something that can calculate NewDate=(OldDate - 1day.2months.12hours), so I don't have to calculate the difference and enter the date for every file?

Answer (score 2):

[exiv2](http://linux.die.net/man/1/exiv2) should be the easiest solution to do this:

```
exiv2 -O -2 -D -1 -a -12:00:00 adjust /path/to/copy/*.jpg
```

Excerpt from the man page:

```
exiv2 - Image metadata manipulation tool 
exiv2 [options] [action] file ...

ad | adjust
    Adjust Exif timestamps by the given time. Requires at least one of the options -a time, -Y yrs, -O mon or -D day.

-a time
    Time adjustment in the format [-]HH[:MM[:SS]]. This option is only used with the 'adjust' action. Examples: 1 adds one hour, 1:01 adds one hour and one minute, -0:00:30 subtracts 30 seconds. 
-Y yrs
    Time adjustment by a positive or negative number of years, for the 'adjust' action. 
-O mon
    Time adjustment by a positive or negative number of months, for the 'adjust' action. 
-D day
    Time adjustment by a positive or negative number of days, for the 'adjust' action.
```

Also, I'd suggest you try this first on a copy of the photos, not on the originals.

Comment: i'll give it a try :)